# Excel VBA - Works for 1 cell, cannot modify to do multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for any help. Tried searching for a few hours. I almost have this macro working perfectly, I just don't know how to do a slight modification:

This one works perfectly, but only for 1 row:

```
Sub UpdateStatusTest01()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("test")
Set s2 = Sheets("SIGNUPS")
v1 = s1.Range("A2")
v2 = s1.Range("B2")
s2.Activate
For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
    If r.Value = v1 Then
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = v2
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I'd like it to move onto the next row of the "SIGNUPS" sheet, and keep finding/matching/replacing column B data for rows past B2. If I try to modify

```
v1 = s1.Range("A2")
v2 = s1.Range("B2")
```

Into

```
v1 = s1.Range("A:A")
v2 = s1.Range("B:B")
```

The code becomes

```
Sub UpdateStatusTest01()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("test")
Set s2 = Sheets("SIGNUPS")
v1 = s1.Range("A:A")
v2 = s1.Range("B:B")
s2.Activate
For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
    If r.Value = v1 Then
        r.Offset(0, 1).Value = v2
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

But excel does not like this line:

```
If r.Value = v1 Then
```

It only happens when the modified range is changed from 1 cell into a whole column. The exact error is "Run-time error '13': type mismatch".

I know I'm suppose to modify that troublesome line, but I don't know what to put in to account for a range with multiple cells. I'd appreciate any help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA simply doesn't understand what you want. Either iterate trough each possibility or do a lookup like this:

```
Sub UpdateStatusTest01()
  Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
  Dim v1 As Range, v2 As Range
  Set s1 = Sheets("test")
  Set s2 = Sheets("SIGNUPS")
  Set v1 = s1.Range("A:A")
  Set v2 = s1.Range("B:B")
  s2.Activate
  For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(r.Value, v1, 0)) Then
      r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.Index(v2, Application.Match(r.Value, v1, 0))
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Hopefully that is what you are looking for (to me it is not 100% clear what you want).

It simply checks `v1` to have the value you desire and prints the value of `v2` from the same row.

The error itself is simply because you try to compare (`=`) an array which is not possible for VBA.

However, a task as simple as this, also could be done via worksheet-formulas ;)

Comment: Wow you are the man! This is perfect. Ahhh I completely understand now. I end up jumbling a lot of SQL into my head, and suffer for that. Thank you x1000